# Check if timestamp is within the next N minutes window using Bash

Tags: bash, time, compare

I want to check if a timestamp is within the **next** 30 minutes using Bash.

What i've done is:

`if [ $a -lt $(($(date +%s) + 30*60)) ] ; then`

Here, `$a` is my timestamp that i want to check. However, this gives a match not only for the next 30 minutes (that is what i want), but also for the 30-minute window that have already passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test that you implemented checks if the TIMESTAMP < (NOW+30min). This will result is all past dates (e.g., 2010) being accepted.

Consider changing to test to the range NOW:NOW+30minutes

```
NOW=$(date '+%s')
if [ "$a" -ge "$NOW" -a "$a" -lt "$((NOW+30*60)) ] ; then
...
```